# Java writing for loop with user input

Tags: java

/**I am trying to ask for user input for the number of the books they want to order, then using for find the cost of each book, total them up and give them their receipt at the end for their order. I understand how to give them the output just having trouble with my loop.*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookOrder {
    public static void main(String[] orgs){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final double TAX = .065;
        final double SHIPPING = 2.95;
        int counter = 0;

        double bookSubtotal, subtotal, taxPaid;
        System.out.print("Please enter the  number of books you're ordering: ");
        double  numberOfBooks = in.nextDouble();
        for (counter = 0; counter < numberOfBooks; counter++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the cost of your book: ");
            double priceOfBooks = in.nextDouble();
            bookSubtotal = priceOfBooks + bookSubtotal;
            counter ++;

        }

        double subtotal = numberOfBooks * priceOfBooks;
        double taxpaid = subtotal * (TAX);
        double shippingCharge = SHIPPING * numberOfBooks;
        double sumOfOrder = bookSubtotal + priceOfOrder + shippingCharge + TAX;

            System.out.println("Number of books purchased:" + numberOfBooks);
            System.out.println("Book subtotal: $" + subtotal);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + taxPaid);
            System.out.println("Shipping: $" + shippingCharge);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("The price of the order is $" + sumOfOrder + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: The "bookSubtotal" variable is not initialized. You should set its value before using. Moreover, you create "subtotal" variable twice. On the other hand, local variable "priceOfBooks" is defined in for loop, so that you can use it just inside it, not outside.

Comment: `"having trouble with my loop"` - What "trouble"?  We can't see your screen from here, describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to increment counter twice:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < numberOfBooks; counter++){
        System.out.println("Please enter the cost of your book: ");
        double priceOfBooks = in.nextDouble();
        bookSubtotal = priceOfBooks + bookSubtotal;
        counter ++;//this line

}
```

What happens in `this line` is that you increment `counter`, but the loop does that for you, because of:

```
for(counter = 0;counter<numberOfBooks;counter++)
```

the `counter++` in that line increments `counter` for you, so just remove the

```
counter++;
```

line in the for loop (the one I wrote `this line` next to)

Also, you should set a value to `bookSubtotal`:

```
int bookSubtotal = 0;
```

in the beginning.

Additionally, you might want to make `numberOfBooks` an integer:

```
int numberOfBooks = in.nextInt();
```

And you shouldn't re declare `subtotal` twice, just remove the word `double` in the line:

```
double subtotal = (double)numberOfBooks * priceOfBooks;
```

Nor do you need the create `taxpaid` before the loop, because you have `taxPaid` after it. Naming is case sensitive, meaning capital letters Are ImpOrtaNt...

Comment: thank you very much Itamar Green that was very helpful and got me where I needed to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BookOrder {
    public static void main(String[] orgs){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final double TAX = .065;
        final double SHIPPING = 2.95;
        int counter = 0;

        double bookSubtotal = 0;
        System.out.print("Please enter the  number of books you're ordering: ");
        int numberOfBooks = in.nextInt();
        for (counter = 0; counter < numberOfBooks; counter++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the cost of your book: ");
            double priceOfBooks = in.nextDouble();
            bookSubtotal += priceOfBooks;

        }

        double shippingCharge = SHIPPING * numberOfBooks;
        double tax = TAX * bookSubtotal;
        double sumOfOrder = bookSubtotal + shippingCharge + tax;
            System.out.println("Number of books purchased:" + numberOfBooks);
            System.out.println("Book subtotal: $" + bookSubtotal);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + tax);
            System.out.println("Shipping: $" + shippingCharge);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("The price of the order is $" + sumOfOrder + ".");
            }
}
```